# How do i improve this bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Here's the code:

javascript:(function()%7B%20window.open('http://www.google.com/');%20%7D)();%20javascript:(function()%7B%20window.open('http://www.magesy.me/');%20%7D)();

How can i get like a two or three second delay on the second tab opening?

Comment: `javascript:open('http://www.google.com/');setTimeout(function(){open('http://www.magesy.me/')},2000);void(0);` untested but should do the trick.

Comment: If delayed, it will be catched by your pop-up blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`

```
(function() 
 {
  window.open('www.google.com');
  setTimeout(function() {
     window.open('www.magesy.com');
 }, 1000); 
})();
```

Where 1000 is the timeout in milliseconds.  To get a longer delay adjust this to 2000 (2 seconds)